# Modified moment locale for bootstrapMaterialDatePicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

hi i want change my moment english locale to french  i modified my file bootstrapMaterialDatePicker.js but dosn't work

```
 moment.locale('fr');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the bootstrapMaterialDatePicker from here:
https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker

And what I did was to add moment.js, also with moment-with-locales.min.js, and then for it to be applied to the bootstrapMaterialDatePicker you should pass the options like this:

```
$('#datepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format : 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    lang : 'nl'        
});
```

Then that will get the moment-locales.js file and put the correct language to it.

Hope this helps.